# vue3 passing prop object into LocalStorage on Component @click

Tags: json, vuejs3, local-storage

I'm trying to pass a prop (faction) from a Component (Faction Option) on the @click event for the option.

**FactionOption.vue**

```js
<script setup>
import { selectFaction } from '../../composables/selectFaction';

defineProps({
    faction: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
})

function setFaction(f) {
    selectFaction(f)
}

</script>

<template>
    <div class="option">
        <p class="option__text">{{ faction.name }} - {{ faction.title }}</p>
        <button class="button button--link" key="select" @click="setFaction(faction)">Select</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

The above is passing the Object into selectedFaction.ts just fine:

**selectFaction.ts**

```js
import { toRaw } from "vue";
import { selectedFaction } from "./useFactions";

export function selectFaction(faction) {
    const theFaction = selectedFaction();
    const rawObject = toRaw(faction);
    console.log(rawObject)
    console.log(theFaction.value)

    return () => {
        theFaction.value = [rawObject];
    };
}
```

Console is accurately converting the object into it's raw value from proxy.

**useFactions.ts**

```js
import { Faction } from "../models/Faction";
import { createGlobalState, useLocalStorage } from "@vueuse/core";

export const selectedFaction = createGlobalState(() => {
    return useLocalStorage<Faction[]>("@battleline/selectedFaction", []);
});
```

However, when the button is clicked, a blank array is inserted into LocalStorage for "@battleline/selectedFaction".

I'm fairly new to Vue3, why is this returning a blank array? TYIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
return () => {
  theFaction.value = [rawObject];
};
```

This means you're returning a function that will perform the inner statement only once that function is called.

Your component would need to assign this return value to some const so it could then call it:

```js
const returnedFunction = selectFaction(f)
returnedFunction()
```

or just

```js
selectFaction(f)()
```

Alternatively, you don't *have* to return anything from your `selectFaction` composable. If all you want is to set your global state / localStorage, this will do the job, and **FactionOption.vue** won't need any changes:

```js
export function selectFaction(faction) {
  const theFaction = selectedFaction();
  const rawObject = toRaw(faction);
  theFaction.value = [rawObject]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was overthinking it, appreciate the answer!